# How is rawPrediction calculated in PySpark RandomForest implementation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, classification, random-forest, apache-spark-mllib

I have trained an RF model (with 3 trees and the depth of 4) on a training set of 15 examples. Below is the image of how the three trees look. I have two classes (say 0 and 1).

[image: The three decision trees]

The thresholds are mentioned on the left branch whereas the number in circles (for example 7, 3 are the number of examples that were <= threshold and > threshold for the feature 2 i.e. f2).

Now when I try to apply the model on the test set of 10 examples, I am not sure how the raw prediction is calculated.

```
+-----+----+----+----------+-------------------------------------------------------------------
|prediction|features                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   |rawPrediction|probability                            |
+-----+----+----+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------+---------------------------------------+
|1.0       |[0.07707524933080619,0.03383458646616541,0.017208413001912046,9.0,2.5768015000258258,0.0,-1.0,-1.0,0.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,-1.0,0.0014143059186559938,0.0,0.6666666666666667,7.076533785087878E-4,0.0014163090128755495,0.9354143466934853,0.9333333333333333,0.875,0.938888892531395,7.0]                 |[1.0,2.0]    |[0.3333333333333333,0.6666666666666666]|
```

I have gone through the following links out there to understand but I am not able to get my head around this.

https://forums.databricks.com/questions/14355/how-does-randomforestclassifier-compute-the-rawpre.html

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/RandomForestClassifier.scala

I know for sure that it's not as straightforward as you think. For example from my understanding, it is not like - for example, if two trees predict 0 and one tree predict as 1 then the raw prediction would be [2, 1]. This is not the case because when I train the model on 500 examples I see the raw prediction for the same example to be [0.9552544653780279,2.0447455346219723].

Can someone explain this to me how mathematically this is being calculated? Any help would be appreciated here as it's kinda basic and I want to get my head straight on how this is working. Again thanks a lot in advance and please post if there is any other information required to help resolve this.

**Edit:**
Adding the data from the model as well:

```
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|treeID|nodeData                                                                                             |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|0     |[0, 0.0, 0.5, [9.0, 9.0], 0.19230769230769235, 1, 4, [2, [0.12519961673586713], -1]]                 |
|0     |[1, 0.0, 0.42603550295857984, [9.0, 4.0], 0.42603550295857984, 2, 3, [20, [0.39610389610389607], -1]]|
|0     |[2, 0.0, 0.0, [9.0, 0.0], -1.0, -1, -1, [-1, [], -1]]                                                |
|0     |[3, 1.0, 0.0, [0.0, 4.0], -1.0, -1, -1, [-1, [], -1]]                                                |
|0     |[4, 1.0, 0.0, [0.0, 5.0], -1.0, -1, -1, [-1, [], -1]]                                                |
|1     |[0, 1.0, 0.4444444444444444, [5.0, 10.0], 0.4444444444444444, 1, 2, [4, [0.9789660448762616], -1]]   |
|1     |[1, 1.0, 0.0, [0.0, 10.0], -1.0, -1, -1, [-1, [], -1]]                                               |
|1     |[2, 0.0, 0.0, [5.0, 0.0], -1.0, -1, -1, [-1, [], -1]]                                                |
|2     |[0, 0.0, 0.48, [3.0, 2.0], 0.48, 1, 2, [20, [0.3246753246753247], -1]]                               |
|2     |[1, 0.0, 0.0, [3.0, 0.0], -1.0, -1, -1, [-1, [], -1]]                                                |
|2     |[2, 1.0, 0.0, [0.0, 2.0], -1.0, -1, -1, [-1, [], -1]]                                                |
+------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The raw prediction is the predicted class probabilities for each tree, summed over all trees in the forest.
For the class probabilities for a single tree, the number of samples belonging to each class in the selected leaf node matters.

In the code, we can see this procedure in the `RandomForestClassifier` class [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/classification/RandomForestClassifier.scala#L218), the relevant code is quoted here:

> ```scala
> override protected def predictRaw(features: Vector): Vector = {
>   // TODO: When we add a generic Bagging class, handle transform there: SPARK-7128
>   // Classifies using majority votes.
>   // Ignore the tree weights since all are 1.0 for now.
>   val votes = Array.fill[Double](numClasses)(0.0)
>   _trees.view.foreach { tree =>
>     val classCounts: Array[Double] = tree.rootNode.predictImpl(features).impurityStats.stats
>     val total = classCounts.sum
>     if (total != 0) {
>       var i = 0
>       while (i < numClasses) {
>         votes(i) += classCounts(i) / total
>         i += 1
>       }
>     }
>   }
>   Vectors.dense(votes)
> }
> ```

For each tree, we find the leaf node corresponding to the input feature and find the count for each class (the class count corresponds to the number of training samples of the class assigned to the leaf node during training). The class counts are divided by the total count of the node to get class probabilities.

Now, for each tree, we have the probability of the input features belonging to each class. These probabilities are summed to get the raw predictions.

---

**More specific for this question**, from my understanding the main missing element is the class count (and from that, class probabilities). To calculate the raw prediction, these are an essential component. In the image, instead of having "Pred 0" and "Pred 1", you need to add the number of samples during training that gets assigned to each leaf ("Pred 0" would mean that the number of samples from class 0 are a majority, and vice versa). When you know the class counts and class probabilities, sum these for all the trees and you get the raw prediction.

Comment: @shaido-reinstate-monica This was helpful. I saved the model and then read the data and treeData. From the data, I figured out the impurity stats. I have updated the question with those details. I was able to understand how rawPrediction is calculated. But now the question is - looking at the impurityStats array I have no idea how that is generated in the first place. The total of the impurity stats array exceeds the number of training examples used which I am not able to understand. If you can help - it would be great. Thanks!

Comment: @yguw: The data you posted is not only impurity stats, there is lots of information contained there. In the data you added, each row is representing a node in the trees (with the first tree having 5 nodes and the two others 3 nodes each). A random forest classifier will consider a random selection of the samples for each tree. From the data we can see that the first tree considers 18 samples (9 of each class), the second tree considers 15 samples (5 and 10 of each class) and the last tree 5 samples (3 and 2). Gini impurity is usually used for RFs and it's calculated for each node.

Comment: Since the purity of the nodes will increase lower in the trees, the gini impurity will decrease. A good explaination of how it's used/calculated can be found here: https://victorzhou.com/blog/gini-impurity/

Comment: @shaido-reinstate-monica thank you so much. Now, the only question I have is how come the sample size is 18 for the first tree when I have used only 15 examples to train my data. Basically, my training data was 15 examples then how come the first tree has considered 18 samples? If you can help me understand this - I will be done for now. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I guess it's using bootstrapping but that was not clear from the pyspark documentation.

Comment: @yguw: Correct, looking at the code, bootstraping is automatically used in Spark 2.4 and older if the number of trees is > 1 ([link](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.4/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/ml/tree/impl/RandomForest.scala#L132)). For Spark 3.0 there is a boolean parameter "bootstrap" that can be set to control this behavior.

Comment: @shaido-reinstate-monica I have a request for you to please look into this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61718373/pyspark-mllib-random-forest-classifier-repeatability-issue